# C# Удалить границы TabControl или установить другой цвет

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я переделал TabControl, на расположение вкладок слева, путем создания компонента. Но я не могу поменять цвет или стереть границы, выделил на скриншоте.

Вот полный код

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestControlTabControl
{


    public partial class UserTabControl: TabControl
    {
        public UserTabControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
            Alignment = TabAlignment.Left;
            DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            ItemSize = new Size(30, 60);
        }
        protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDrawItem(e);
            e.Graphics.SetClip(e.Bounds);
            string text = TabPages[e.Index].Text;
            SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, e.Font);

            bool bSelected = (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected;
            Color customColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.FromArgb(2, 27, 30));
            SolidBrush shadowBrush = new SolidBrush(customColor);
            // using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(bSelected ? SystemColors.Highlight : SystemColors.Control))
            //   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(shadowBrush, e.Bounds);
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, this.GetTabRect(this.SelectedIndex));

            using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(bSelected ? SystemColors.Menu: SystemColors.Menu))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(shadowBrush, e.Bounds);
            using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(bSelected ? SystemColors.HighlightText : SystemColors.ControlText))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, b, e.Bounds.X + 2, e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2);

            if (SelectedIndex == e.Index)
            {
             e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(shadowBrush, this.GetTabRect(this.SelectedIndex));
            }
            

            e.Graphics.ResetClip();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если пишете на WPF, можете сделать кастомные стили (Style). Достаточно много уроков на ютюбе по запросу "wpf design ui"

Comment: Возмите какую-нибудь готовую библиотеку типа MaterialDesign

Comment: Вам же написано winforms, при чём тут WPF

Comment: @aepot взял за пример metroUI посмотрел реализацию, проще наследовать дочерние формы в  Panel чем переоределить TabControl. Я смог поменять цвет везде, кроме одного места: https://skr.sh/sGtpdLCcWth видна рамка из белого цвета, это места не могу изменить